# IIS Giving 404 on images in some locations

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I am going nuts trying to figure this out.  In my .net core app I allow a user to upload images, and I save them in the content root (using `IWebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath`).  I have two applications that run on my site (windows server 12 and IIS 8.5):

```
http://server/app1
http://server/app2
```

The applications have virtual path set up to use /app1 and /app2 respectively in IIS. (not virtual directories, just the virtual path).  The physical location for the applications is similarly the same:

```
c:\sites\webroot\app1
c:\sites\webroot\app2
```

I have made an images subfoler in each of the applications virtual path, and I can upload images with `<input type=file/>` elements posting data back to the controller (this uses windows paths not Url paths).

In my browser I can manually go to the app1/images/test.jpg and see the image.  But if I put the same image in the app2/images folder and then browse to it I get a 404 error.

Both folders have the same IIS IUSRS user with read and execute permissions (permissions for each images folder and site folders are identical).  I cannot figure out why I can write images into the app2 folder but cannot view them in a web page.